# How to generalize a Moore Curve to 3 dimensions?

Tags: fractals

I understand the concept of a [Moore curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_curve) in 2D:

[image]

However I find it a bit tough to conceptualize and generalize it to 3D or higher dimensions. Can someone kindly help me out by providing some resources and maybe a computer code to do so ?

Regards

Ujjwal

Comment: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/HilbertAndMoore3DFractalCurves/

You can see some iterations here.  I think that gives a general idea for conceptualization.

Comment: What is the mathematical form of Moore curve and its generation principle in an arbitrary dimension ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a L-System but it's not trivial at all. It's also possible to use the gray-code.  The trick is in 2d you have only 1 possible gray code:http://www.tiac.net/~sw/2008/10/Hilbert/ and look this answer:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14519267/algorithm-for-generating-a-3d-hilbert-space-filling-curve-in-python

Comment: Your links appear to be combined.